# How can i use java variable value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, xhtml

I don't know if this is realizable, because i don't have strong knowledge in JavaScript.

I want to use Java variable in Javascript and XHTML code, i have a file path in java variable: `applicationDadesVersioBB.rutaFitxerLog` which i display as follows in XHTML page in a table as follows:

```
<tr>
  <th scope="row">#{literalsCore['Entorn.FitxerLog']}</th>
  <td>
     <a href="#{applicationDadesVersioBB.rutaFitxerLog}"  onClick="descarga([[${applicationDadesVersioBB.rutaFitxerLog}]])">#{applicationDadesVersioBB.rutaFitxerLog}</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

until now everything is fine, but what I want to do is once the path is clicked, the file should be downloaded, which i am not able to do with: `onClick="descarga([[${applicationDadesVersioBB.rutaFitxerLog}]])`

the JavaScript descarga function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function descarga(file)
    {
        window.location=file;
    }
</script>
```

I think the problem I have is the conversion of java variable values to javascript values.

I tried to do it changing the `onClick="descarga([[${applicationDadesVersioBB.rutaFitxerLog}]])"` to `onClick="descarga("#{applicationDadesVersioBB.rutaFitxerLog}")"`

but no way, any help?

Comment: `which i am not able to do with` - why? what's the problem?

Comment: The file path is displayed correctly, but when i click it, i suppose it should calls the descarga function i have in my code to download the file, but it is not working, it does not download the file.

Comment: What is the definition of `descarga` ?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI do you mean its implementation ?

Comment: yes > >implementation

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function descarga(file)
    {
        window.location=file;
    }
</script>

i don't know if it is correct.

Comment: you don't need `onclick` ,because `href` is enough & both open other URL . 
If you want to work with `onclick`, put `href="#"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118516/discussion-between-abdennour-toumi-and-rainman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need quotes around a string

```
onClick="descarga('[[${applicationDadesVersioBB.rutaFitxerLog}]]')"
```

Comment: i get this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 20: http://0.0.0.0//agd/[[C:Documentumlogslog4j.log]]
 at org.ocpsoft.urlbuilder.util.Decoder.path(Decoder.java:19)
 at org.ocpsoft.urlbuilder.AddressBuilder.pathEncoded(AddressBuilder.java:147)
 at org.ocpsoft.urlbuilder.AddressBuilderPort.pathEncoded(AddressBuilderPort.java:54)
 at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.BaseHttpRewrite.getInboundAddress(BaseHttpRewrite.java:88)
 at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpInboundRewriteImpl.getAddress(HttpInboundRewriteImpl.java:

Comment: i suppose because it's a file i have localy and nor an URL right ?

Comment: Ehm... why do you need to download a file that you have locally already?

Comment: I have it localy because i am making tests localy before i display my application in a remote oracle weblogic server, then it will not be a local file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you're trying to do but I remeber a useful "hack" to do that in PHP for example... You have to create a hidden input in your HTML file and set its value to applicationDadesVersioBB.rutaFitxerLog. Then in your click handler you just get the input element thanks to its id for example and you read the value.

Hope it helps